# Making current function of list recursive Clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure

Hi i am looking for a bit of help with some Clojure code.  I have written a function that will take in a list and calculate the qty*price for a list eg.    '(pid3 6 9)

What i am looking for is to expand my current function so that it recursively does the qty*price calculation until it reaches the end of the list.

My current function is written like this:

```
(defn pid-calc [list] (* (nth list 1) (nth list 2)))
```

I have tried implementing it into a recursive function but have had no luck at all, i want to be able to call something like this:

```
(pid-calcc '( (pid1 8 5) (pid2 5 6))
 return==> 70
```

Thats as close as i have came to an answer and cannot seem to find one.  If anyone can help me find a solution i that would be great. As so far i am yet to find anything that will compile.

```
​(defn pid-calc [list]
   (if(empty? list)
    nil
    (* (nth list 1) (nth list 2)(+(pid-calc (rest list))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a recursive function. Just use `+` and `map`:

```
(defn pid-calc [list]
  (letfn [(mul [[_ a b]] (* a b))]
    (apply + (map mul list))))
```

Comment: Define `list-calc`, say as `(fn [[_ a b]] (* a b))`.

Comment: @Thumbnail thanks. OP edited his question and removed the definition of `list-calc`, so I edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

[@sloth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33436287/1562315), suitably corrected, is a concise and fast enough way to solve your problem. It shows you a lot.

Your attempt at a recursive solution can be (a)mended to

```
(defn pid-calc [list]
   (if (empty? list)
    0
    (let [x (first list)]
      (+ (* (nth x 1) (nth x 2)) (pid-calc (next list))))))
```

This works on the example, but - being properly recursive - will run out of stack space on a long enough list. The limit is usually about 10K items.

We can get over this without being so concise as @sloth. You might find the following easier to understand:

```
(defn pid-calc [list]
  (let [line-total (fn [item] (* (nth item 1) (nth item 2)))]
    (apply + (map line-total list))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, im pretty much just getting started with clojure. I have only ever really written in OO languages.  There is so much more i need to learn, i knew i could simply most of my functions to one liners almost but i dont know what all of the built in methods do yet.

Answer (score 0):

[`reduce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) fits your scenario quite well:

```
(def your-list [[:x 1 2] [:x 1 3]])

(reduce #(+ %1 (* (nth %2 1) (nth %2 2))) 0 your-list)

(reduce #(+ %1 (let [[_ a b] %2] (* a b)) 0 your-list)
```